# how to move cursor effectively in "last line mode" of vi?

Tags: vim, vi

[image]

I mean, how to move cursor forward or backward in last line mode.

You know, hjkl can be used in command mode. But when we type :, we will enter into "last line mode". But in this mode, I have to use the left/right arrow to move cursor.

So my question is: can I use hjkl to move cursor in last line mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That mode is called *command-line mode*. Yes, there is limited navigation in there (the list of commands starts at `:help c_CTRL-V`); most keys are inserted literally. This is because the mode is not meant for intensive editing; you're supposed to only type *new* commands, or do minor corrections to a recalled older one.

If you do need the full editing capabilities, just switch to the *command-line window*. You can do this by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> from the command-line, or just immediately enter it via `q:` instead of `:` (and likewise `q/` instead of `/`). Cp. `:help cmdwin`

Comment: Thanks. The final solution is q: and q/. After that, I can type commands or strings by "vi" style.